# How to mailto to office 365?

Tags: html, href, office365, outlook-web-app

How to `mailto` to office 365 like this one on the gmail - [Open Gmail on mailto: action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988355/open-gmail-no-mailto-action).

I have this link:

> https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#viewmodel=IMailComposeViewModelFactory

but I have no idea for recipient parameter to put in the `TO`. Please help guys.

Here's how it do it in Gmail:

```
<a href="https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=email@domain.com">sample@domain.com</a>
```

Now here's what i do in Office 365 but i dont know what is the right parameter for the Recipient:

```
<a href="https://pod51038.outlook.com/owa/#viewmodel=IMailComposeViewModelFactory">sample@domain.com</a>
```

Comment: did you ever figure it out?

Comment: this thread suggests it is not feasible : https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/158/t/358769 dated July 2015..

Answer (score 21):

Office 365 now supports composing an email using a URL:

```
https://outlook.office.com/?path=/mail/action/compose&to=service@domain.com&subject=Customer Service Request&body=Add+Your+Request+here
```

available parameters:

- **path**   /mail/action/compose
- **subject**   Customer Service Request
- **body**  Add your request here
- **to**    service@domain.com
- **cc** is not supported at this point.

See
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carloshm/2016/01/16/how-to-compose-a-new-message-or-event-and-populate-fields-in-office365/#comment-1645 for more details

Comment: Combine this answer with that article https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/02/Getting-Gmail-to-handle-all-mailto-links-with-registerProtocolHandler for a working mailto feature

Comment: This is no longer correct. It's been replaced with a new URL structure: https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose

Answer (score 4):

[This extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailto/gppbppehiogfokmpligejhaepeopajdf?hl=en) worked for me. I just had to edit the Outlook.com url by clicking on "change" and editing it to be something like:

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=example.com&rru=compose&to={to}&subject={subject}&body={body}&cc={cc}
```

Where example.com should be replaced by your organizations Outlook 365 domain.

I should note that I am on Debian linux with no default email client set at the moment. However, I don't see how that might have any effect as I believe this extension might be simply altering the url that is opened to go to a different url. I could be wrong about this last part since I haven't looked into the extension code.

Comment: it works for me but after one second I lost my new mail screen and outlook 365 redirects to main outlook page

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done without using a 3rd party app or setting OWA as the default mail agent on the client computer.
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/38d11e6d-8009-4d7d-8d69-a6701860feb8/setting-up-owa-to-be-used-by-mailto-protocol

Set OWA as default mail agent:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmeston/archive/2004/01/08/48837.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After the recent changes what works for me is:

```
https://outlook.office.com/mail/0/deeplink/compose?popoutv2=1&to=[EMAIL_ADDRESS]&subject=[SUBJECT]&body=[BODY]
```