# Make link to starts to create a new e-mail with owa of outlook365

Tags: email, outlook, html-email, outlook-web-app

Now I have this code:

```
mailto:{0}?subject={1}&body={2}
```

This open my default mail program (in my company outlook) and write {0} in To: {1} in subjet and {2} in body.

But now some people in company starts to work with OWA of office365

I can't continue using mailto: because I can't configure OWA like a programn in windows.

I try with this ways.

1. Link with parameters

   ```
   https://outlook.office.com/?path=/mail/action/compose&to={0}&subject={1}&body={0}
   ```

   This seems to work but after one second the webpage make redirect and I lost my e-mail.
2. Link direct to new e-mail

   ```
   https://outlook.office365.com/owa/#viewmodel=IMailComposeViewModelFactory
   ```

   But this open a new e-mail but I don't know how to send parameters.

Answer (score 0):

see [How to mailto to office 365?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714746/how-to-mailto-to-office-365)

in 2023 the syntax is

```
https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?to=service@domain.com&subject=Customer%20Service%20Request&body=Add%20Your%20Request%20here
```