# Email to link with email parameter opens outlook in browser starts new email

Tags: html, outlook, office365, html-email

**I am looking to replace for "mailto:" that redirect users to their outlook account in browser and do new email with the email in the link.**

`mailto:` works for all users if they have set up default application outlook locally.

```
<a href="mailto:example@outlook.com">Send Email</a>
```

This opens the default email application to send new email to 'example@outlook.com'

I want to use this specifically for office365 outlook mail users, so instead of using default app, I need something for example:

```
<a href="http://sendemailusingoutlook?toEmail=example@outlook.com">Send Email</a>
```

And when user clicks on 'Send Email' It should open the office365 outlook in browser and have new email to 'example@outlook.com'

Is there any possible way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following url to launch email from the outlook online, you can modify the email address, subject, and email body.

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/mail/action/compose&to=emailname@domain.com&subject=Email%20Subject%20Here&body=some+content+goes+here
```

Link to compose outlook email:

```
https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/mail/action/compose
```

Pass parameters in URL based on your usecase:

```
&to=emailname@domain.com
&subject=Email%20Subject%20Here
&body=some+content+goes+here
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly.

Comment: @LaharShah, are your email users only using outlook 365? What about the others who dont use 365? (Just curious)

Comment: @Syfer Yes, all users are on office365 and I want them to use that.

Comment: can we pass attachment as the parameter in it?

Answer (score -1):

as of 2023 the syntax is

```
https://outlook.office.com/mail/deeplink/compose?to=service@domain.com&subject=Customer%20Service%20Request&body=Add%20Your%20Request%20here
```

see [How to mailto to office 365?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714746/how-to-mailto-to-office-365) as well

Comment: Please don't post the [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76322144/10871073) to multiple questions.