# O365 OWA Reply or Reply To All viewmodel or action

Tags: office365, outlook-web-app

As we have the viewmodels to create a new mail or to read existing one, I assume there is an option to automatically open the mail by id in the Reply or Reply To all Mode.
These 2 are obvious:

```
viewmodel=IMailComposeViewModelFactory

viewmodel=ReadMessageItem
```

My question: Is there one for reply like

```
viewmodel=ReplyMessageItem(itemID)
```

Or is there any other way of doing so?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as I understand, there is no feature with ReplyItem to achieve it. Since there are limitations for the "URL way". You can refer to the following link:

[How to mailto to office 365?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714746/how-to-mailto-to-office-365)