# Use URL to compose Outlook Web App mail with attachments

Tags: office365, email-attachments, outlook-web-app

We're trying to add a simple integration with Office365 to replace the traditional mailto functionality.

I recently discovered the method of using the outlook.office compose path to launch the clients Outlook Web App with the To, Subject and Body populated.

Thanks to this post ([How to mailto to office 365?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714746/how-to-mailto-to-office-365))

I'm however trying to figure out how to add an attachment.

Any ideas of how I can achieve this and I've tried the following:

I've tried including it as base64 in the body which didn't work.

```
https://outlook.office.com/?path=/mail/action/compose&to=service@domain.com&subject=Customer Service Request&body=Add+Your+Request+here
```

Desired outcome:
- User clicks on an 'Email' link in our custom application
- The link opens the users OWA composed email in a new tab/window with the subject line and body populated and an attachment added to the mail.
- User send mail from OWA

Any help will be super helpful, thanks.

Comment: did you find any way to achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

The format for outlook urls looks like this:

```
https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink/compose?subject=SUBJECT&body=BODY&to=email@example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

For outlook try this,

```
https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/deeplink/compose?to=your@email.com
```

this should open up the outlook web mailer.