# CC,BCC property not working in outlook email compose option in javascript

Tags: javascript, outlook, cc, bcc

In my requirement I need to implement email option. By default I have to open outlook as default composer. I am using below code to open outlook as default

```
 var mailData = 'https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/mail/action/compose&to=' + actionData['to'] + '&subject=' + actionData['subject'] + '&body='+actionData['body']+'&CC='+actionData['cc']+'&bcc='+actionData['bcc']
    window.open(mailData, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=600,width=900,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
```

But CC,BCC property not working

How to resolve this error

Comment: you use `CC` and `bcc` ... is **case** important?

Comment: @Bravo thanks for reply.I have tried different cases such as(cc,CC,Cc,bcc,BCC,Bcc) even its not working

Comment: are all the parameters properly escaped? i.e. do you have `&` in the body for example? have you tried moving cc and bcc before the body?

Comment: [This older SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40477920/8376184) says that the `cc` field is not implemented (I assume the same goes for `bcc`); but a comment points out that it applies to an outdated format (apparently, so does your question). I don't know if the new format supports those fields and how to use it, though.

Comment: the old link redirects to the new mail/deeplink link - and you're right @FZs cc is not supported