# Link to mail server from website

Tags: html, email, mail-server

I have an email page on my website with a form and `tinyMCE` and all that fancy stuff, but I also want to add a couple of links to the popular mail servers such as `gmail`, `yahoo`, and `hotmail`.

I've seen some links that go to the my `Microsoft Office Outlook` (which I never use), and I've also seen a `gmail` link that opens up `gmail` in a new tab with a form already open and a mailto: value already given. Just wondering how this is done if I, lets say, have a `mailto:` value to send and perhaps a subject and message.

Just to make it clear, I want three or four image links on my page, each one for a different mail server (`gmail`, `yahoo`...) and when clicked on, it opens a form partly filled out (a `mailto:`value and possibly a subject and/or message) fullscreen. Thanks.

Comment: You could do something like `https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=email@domain.com` for Gmail ([source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988355/open-gmail-on-mailto-action)) but that would require you to regularly check if those links are still working, so I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not going to be easy, as you'll have to integrate with each one of these services. How about going at it a different way? For GMail (at least on Chrome) you can figure the web app as the handler for your mailto: links. With that, you can create a link that opens GMail, optionally with subject and body filled in.  See [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) for details, or try this [link](http://mailto:infobot@example.com?subject=hello&body=hey).

Most users don't have accounts on all of the web mail services you mentioned anyways, and using the mailto link allow the mail to the sent using the user's default e-mail client (may it be Outlook, or GMail) which most people prefer anyways.

Comment: So does all this `mailto:?to=......` stuff go inside a link like so: `<a href="mail to stuff here">service</a>`?

Comment: Yup, a href="mailto:..."

Comment: I tried that and it pulls up Microsoft Outlook, and I use Gmail... regularly. How does it decide which server to pull up?

Comment: No, but your system is configured to use Microsoft Outlook as default e-mail client. Which browser do you use?

Comment: Follow instructions here: http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht will allow you to register GMail to handle mailto: links.

Comment: Thanks. So, then should I just have a link that says something like `Email from Default Service` and then it will just go to whatever they have as default? Is Outlook default for most people?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea -- for the default, it depends on your users. Outlook is only common among Windows machines (even though it's available on Macs but personally I think there are better alternatives) and not available on mobile devices.