# Mailto start a spefic / standard email service

Tags: javascript, html, email, mailto

Is it possible to start a specific or standard email service like thunderbird, if one clicks on the mailto link:

```
<a href="mailto:someone@yoursite.com">Email Us</a>
```

In my case it opens up thunderbird, probably because it is my only email program installed.

But could it be possible to say like open gmail.

Comment: That would be a browser setting. Which browser are you using? And I don't believe it's possible to choose which program to open from JavaScript, so you're stuck with the one choice.

Comment: Maybe this will help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988355/open-gmail-on-mailto-action

Comment: Firefox and Chrom do choose Skype as an application to open the mail.

Comment: It depends on your browser. Here some guideline to set the right email client on you browser http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/set-gmail-as-browser-default-email-client-ht